# Not allowing a prompt to be closed

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to prevent a user from closing a prompt given in Javascript?

I have tried to test if the variable is `null` but that does not seem to work (or I can not figure it out) because once closed I am assuming it does not get to my conditional statement. Is there a way to disable the `close` option in the prompt message?

***I am trying to make the user enter a response in the prompt message box***. I am mostly a C# developer and am learning JS. I do not know how to test this in JS. Forgive me for being a tad confused.

Any help? Thank you all for reading.

---

my code:

```
var login = prompt("Who is this?");

if((login.toUpperCase()) !== "password" || (login === null)) {
alert("BEGIN SHUTDOWN","ERROR");
window.close();
} else {
alert("Access Granted.");
}
```

Comment: ‘*Is there any way to prevent a user from closing a prompt given in Javascript?*’ I sure hope not! That would be horrible!

Comment: Hahaha! I only mean that I want them to have to enter a response to the prompt. I am unsure as to why anyone would downvote a legitimate question.

Comment: You can check the value returned from the prompt and then proceed from there, but there's no way to disable the cancel/close option.

Comment: `[...]I have tried to test if the variable is null but that does not seem to work[...]` how did you try that, and why do you assume that this does not work?

Comment: @j08691 that's what i tried to do with testing if it were `null` or not correct. But I would like to make it towhere the user has to answer it.

Comment: You can use a HTML + Javascript based prompt, instead of using the default browser prompt. http://bootboxjs.com/ You can ensure the prompt is open until user enters something.

Comment: so validation? why not use a input and then just validate or just use the 'required' attribute with regex if you must to get what you desire? i havent seen much people use prompt dialog these days

Comment: @t.niese i tested this using a simple if statement seeing if the prompt was null and no luck. I assume then that closing the prompt does not register the same was as null in the conditional argument.

Comment: @Ashton you should show that code ;) because `var value = prompt('test'); if( value === null ) { }` has to work. So if it does not then you did something wrong. And if you should your code then it is possible to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @t.niese I apologize. i added the code example!

Comment: @Torean i am messing around with the idea that I wanted someone to have to test to even enter my site on a prompt message. that's why. i am simply trying stuff to learn and get used to the language

Comment: With so much discussion and learning going on from this- why would someone downvote me being curious and trying to learn? thanks for all of you guys help!

Comment: @Ashton Reading some of your latest comments this suddenly smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Could it be that what you *really* want is some kind of authentication? If so, there are other (proper) ways to do that.

Comment: Just an amusing detail: `if (login.toUpperCase() !== "password")` will always be `true`.

Comment: @Teemu you are correct! i wrote that in really quick as an example. i would change it to .toLowerCase() or simply add the string comparison to be uppercase by default. thanks!

Comment: @Ashton on last note for future questions. The down vote was most likely because your question was missing your code. More important about that is that before you posted your code most of the questions didn't target your actual mistake. They where not necessarily wrong, but didn't help you to understand why your attempt did not work. So despite avoiding down-votes your should always show a minimal example of your current attempt to get answers fast.

Comment: @t.niese i did add the code after :/ thank you for explaining though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you user closes the dialog then `login` is `null`.

The condition `if ((login.toUpperCase()) !== "password" || (login === null)) {` will first evaluate `login.toUpperCase()`, but because `login` is null it will throw the exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null(…)

You need to test if  `login === null` first:

```
if ( (login === null) || (login.toUpperCase()) !== "password") {
```

Comment: I see. Is this because JS is considered "live" and does not evaluate first before running? Sorry if that's poor wording I am used to OOP with C# and Java. I am not as used to front side stuff!

Comment: @Ashton How should it evaluate the condition before the data is available? And it would be the same problem with any other language too.

Comment: That's the thing it would have gotten the null response before testing the if. Just because it was teh second condition should not mean anything (at least not in java or c# from what ive seen) because it's an OR statement.

Comment: Your answer is correct by the way. Thank you and I am only commenting to try and learn. Thank you!

Comment: @Ashton well it depends on the evaluation order of the `OR` expression in the language. In JS  the left side is evaluated first and then optinally the right side. So as with any other language you need to test in the first evaluated expression (in js the left one)  if the Object/value is `null` (`login === null`)  and only if this evaluates to `false` (if it is not `null`) then the second statement of the `OR` (in js the right one)  is evaluated. But as I said that would be the same thing in other languages only the evaluation order of the `or` expression might be flipped.

Comment: I understand. Whether flipped or not I have not come across that issue ... but that doesn't mean i wouldn't have! thank you for your help- your example make my code work like i wanted it to :)

Answer (score 1):

Check for `null`. If you see `null` prompt again or show a message allowing the user to continue at their convenience.

The native modals (such as `prompt` and `alert`) are quite crude. If it's important enough to you consider implementing your own or using a library.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/37kw50wb/

---

```
<div id="start-container">
  <input id="start" type="button" value="Start"/>
</div>
<div id="continue-container" style="display: none;">
  Please continue when you're ready to enter a value: 
  <input id="continue" type="button" value="Continue"/>
</div>
```

---

```
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("start-container").style.display = "none";
  do_prompt();
});

function do_prompt() {
  var input;
  input = prompt("Enter something");
  if (input === null) {
    document.getElementById("continue-container").style.display = "";
  } else {
    // we have a value, continue your program here
    alert("Thank you");
  }
}

document.getElementById("continue").addEventListener("click", function () {
  do_prompt();
});
```

Comment: i added my simple code example above- my test for null is not working. Any idea why? thank you

Comment: See my code example. Your code doesn't _work_ because `login.toUpperCase` will throw an error if `login` is `null`. Check `null` first and `login.toUpperCase` with a lazy-or (`||`).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty string, and then create the prompt again. See example below:

```
var msg = prompt("Write something here:");
while(msg === "" || msg === null)
{
    //prompt again
}
```

Empty string occurs when user clicks ok with nothing input into the box. Null occurs when user clicks cancel.

Comment: If the user cancels the prompt `null` is returned, not `""`. That said, it might also be worthwhile to check for `""` or any invalid values.

Comment: If user clicks "OK" with nothing in the box, then "" is returned.

Comment: Yes, but the question is what happens when the user closes the prompt without entering anything.

Comment: try this out, but click the "don't let this site show any more prompts" box.. i dare you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a prompt that prevents closure, don't use the javascript `alert` functionality.  Use a modal.  It's basically a prompt that is part of your page.  http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp